# require not loading my file in external package

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to build a plugin manager (migrate to my postgres database, generate CRUD frontend and CRUD GraphQL mutation) as an external package (so I can use it with nextjs and update it without breaking everything) so I nearly finished the project in the same folder but I hated the fact that it was in the same project so I extracted it and built it as an external package.

I'm trying to load classes that are in variable name folders so I tried with

```js
  const files = await fs.readdir('./src/plugins')
  for await (const file of files) {
    const Plugin = await require(`./src/plugins/${file}/index.ts`)
```

the first part with the readdir works but the require makes me an error

```
Error: Cannot find module './src/plugins/example/index.ts'
Require stack:
- E:\nextpower\lib\cjs\commands.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at E:\nextpower\lib\cjs\commands.js:39:34
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (E:\nextpower\lib\cjs\commands.js:7:58) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [ 'E:\\nextpower\\lib\\cjs\\commands.js' ]
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you can't load `ts` file from `js` file

Comment: it's a ts file. and it worked when this code was in the same project.

Comment: You import it from the `nextpower\lib\cjs\commands.js` so I guess it's compiled. You would need to compile ts files before loading them as well

Comment: @Konrad I tried and that's not the problem

```
Error: Cannot find module './src/plugins/example/index.js'
Require stack:
- E:\nextpower\lib\cjs\commands.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:995:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:841:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1061:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:103:18)
    at E:\nextpower\lib\cjs\commands.js:39:34
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (E:\nextpower\lib\cjs\commands.js:7:58) ...
```

Comment: @Konrad it's okay I fixed it I had to use process.cwd